# how to pass both injected and assisted parameters to a Guice Provider?

Tags: guice

I have the following Provider:

```
  public class GuiceResourceProvider implements Provider<WebResource> {

    @Inject
    private Configuration configuration;
    @Inject
    private Environment environment;

    private String name;

    @Inject
    public GuiceResourceProvider(@Assisted("name") String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public WebResource get() {
        if (name == "default") {
            String connectionsDSResourceUrl = "http://localhost:" + this.configuration.getHttpConfiguration().getPort();
            Client connectionsDSHttpClient = new JerseyClientBuilder().using(this.configuration.getHttpClientConfiguration()).using(this.environment).build();
            connectionsDSHttpClient.addFilter(new RequestIdClientFilter());
            return connectionsDSHttpClient.resource(connectionsDSResourceUrl);
        } else if(name == "other"){
            return ......
        }
    }
}
```

I need to create 2 instances of this Provider, one that will bind a WebResource injection annotated with "default" and that will bind a WebResource injection annotated with "other".

Letting Guice to create the Provider instance as follows:

```
    bind(WebResource.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("default")).toProvider(GuiceResourceProvider.class).in(Scopes.SINGLETON);
bind(WebResource.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("other")).toProvider(GuiceResourceProvider.class).in(Scopes.SINGLETON);
```

It is ok for the injected parameters but then i cannot provide a custom one. If i try to instantiate an instance manually and provide the custom parameter, then of course the injected ones have the problem. If i follow the Assisted notation, the problem is that i need to inject the Factory of the Provider in the Module and this, of course, is completely off!

Can anyone help?

Comment: Not sure if `name == "default"`will give you the desired result.

Answer (score 4):

For everyone that might be interested, i found the answer.
If you want to pass both injected AND custom parameters to a Provider, move your injected parameters from the constructor to fields and use the constructor to pass your own parameters. When binding, first create an instance of your Provider passing your parameters to the the constructor, then call requestInjection on this instance in order to add it to the injection graph, and then bind your class to the Provider instance as follows:

```
GuiceResourceProvider guiceResourceProvider = new GuiceResourceProvider("default");
requestInjection(guiceResourceProvider);
```

bind(WebResource.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("default")).toProvider(guiceResourceProvider).in(Scopes.SINGLETON);

This is the Provider:

```
public class GuiceResourceProvider implements Provider<WebResource> {

@Inject
private Configuration configuration;
@Inject
private Environment environment;

private String name;

@Inject
public GuiceResourceProvider(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@Override
public WebResource get() {
    if (name == "default") {
        String connectionsDSResourceUrl = "http://localhost:" + this.configuration.getHttpConfiguration().getPort();
        Client connectionsDSHttpClient = new JerseyClientBuilder().using(this.configuration.getHttpClientConfiguration()).using(this.environment).build();
        connectionsDSHttpClient.addFilter(new RequestIdClientFilter());
        return connectionsDSHttpClient.resource(connectionsDSResourceUrl);
    } else if(name == "other"){
        return ......
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Bear in mind that "assisted injection" tends to refer to accepting a parameter at injection time, not at configuration time. This is a  reasonable solution for refactoring out a general Provider to provide for a finite set of Keys known at configuration time.

Comment: Yes, that's true. Nevertheless, i found some references (one in a book also) that state that if you want pass parameters to a Provider, you can use the Assisted notation. No example is provided though.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things wrong here:

- Don't compare strings with `==`, compare them with `equals`. `==` compares by reference, but the two might be references to different instances of equal strings.
- A Provider is a zero-argument factory. If you have a factory, you don't need a Provider.
- Assisted injection is a different system than binding annotations like `@Named`. Binding annotations are simply half of the map key to look up providers (the Class or TypeLiteral is the other half). Assisted injection allows you to take one or more parameters at injection time, and automatically wire up an interface that does this for you. Assisted-injection parameters only take `@Assisted("foo")` annotations if you accept more than one of the same parameter type in a single factory method; otherwise Guice can figure it out.
- There is no good way to read parameter values in a binding annotation from within the dependency you're injecting--but since binding annotations with different parameter values aren't equal to one another, each one can be bound separately.

I think your logic would look best in a `@Provides` method:

```
public class WebResourceModule extends AbstractModule {

  @Override public void configure() { }

  @Provides @Named("default") @Singleton WebResource makeDefaultResource(
      Configuration configuration, Environment environment) {
    String connectionsDSResourceUrl = "http://localhost:" + this.configuration.getHttpConfiguration().getPort();
    Client connectionsDSHttpClient = new JerseyClientBuilder().using(this.configuration.getHttpClientConfiguration()).using(this.environment).build();
    connectionsDSHttpClient.addFilter(new RequestIdClientFilter());
    return connectionsDSHttpClient.resource(connectionsDSResourceUrl);
  }

  @Provides @Named("other") @Singleton WebResource makeOtherResource(
      YourDependencies here) {
    return somethingElse();
  }
}
```

But if you want to take *any* string with custom factory logic, just create a single-method injectable class that doesn't implement `Provider`, and use it to create and return any `WebResource` you'd like.

Comment: Thank you for your time, but your answer was not helpful at all. You essentially say "don't try to make things complicated, do it simply because it seems you don't understand how it works". Well, this is not the case. I know i can use @provides methods, in fact, this was my first version and it worked pretty well. But now, i'm trying to refactor because i need to create providers and relevant bindings programmatically, based on conditions. This cannot be done, of course, using the special syntax with Provides methods.

Comment: That's not what I'm saying at all. I'm sorry if it came across as condescending--complicated solutions are fine as long as something simpler doesn't suffice. I do stand behind my proposed solutions for the problem as stated, as well as the statement that `@Assisted("name")` will never work for accessing `@Named` annotations, but since you're going through your parameter at compile time, binding your key to an instance of a common Provider makes sense.